# When I inherit from frozenset, I get TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, inheritance, frozenset

I want to inherit from `frozenset` and change the constructor. What I actually want to do is to make a singleton fronzeset, but instead here I'll provide a simplified example:

```py
class B(frozenset):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([1, 2, 3])
```

However, when I try to create an instance of `B`, I get an error:

```py
B()  # TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

What's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For technical reasons, for immutable types like `frozenset` and `tuple`, etc. overriding their `__init__` to set an initial value is the wrong way to go.  This is partly to do with the fact that for the object to be created it has to know how large it's going to be based on the input argument.

You need to override `__new__` instead.  For example:

```
>>> class myset(frozenset):
...     def __new__(cls):
...         return super(myset, cls).__new__(cls, [1, 2, 3])
...     
...     
>>> myset()
myset([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Oh, that's complicated. What is `super(myset, cls)` here? Why do we have both `myset` and `cls` as arguments to `super`? To be clear, I know, approximately, what `super()` does when used in a method that's called on an instance of a class, but here, I don't understand it. And why do you have to pass `cls` as an explicit argument when invoking `super(myset, cls).__new__`?

Comment: I promise it's not that complicated, but it requires some familiarity with the concepts, and especially what `__new__` is and why it exists.  One peculiarity of `__new__` which somewhat violates "explicit over implicit" is that it is always implicitly a static method, which is why you still have to pass the first `cls` argument.

Comment: I should clarify also, in Python 3 it should suffice to just call `super().__new__(cls, [1, 2, 3])`.  For some reason my brain reverted to the Python 2 syntax for a moment :)